# Pass username to flask and retrieve the data using sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, python-3.7

So I have just started studying on flask and am just moving to database with flask. I have a database "testdatabase.db" with a table named "Students". What I want to do is. When i pass a username onto the url I need the details of the that specific row.

Here is my python code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('testdatabase.db')
c = conn.cursor()


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/students/<name>")
def students(name):
    return jam()


def jam():
    c.execute("select * from students where name = '" + name + "'")
    print(c.fetchall())
    conn.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The error being shown is that name 'name' is not defined. How do I define the name to be passed to the url?

Answer (score 1):

Name is being passed correctly to the url

```
@app.route("/students/<name>")
def students(name):
    return jam()
```

Your only problem is that you are not passing it to the `jam` function

**solution**

```
@app.route("/students/<name>")
def students(name):
    return jam(name)

def jam(name):
    c.execute("select * from students where name = '" + name + "'")
    print(c.fetchall())
    conn.close()
    # Return the data jsonfied.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable 'name' in jam, try:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('testdatabase.db')
c = conn.cursor()


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/students/<name>")
def students(name):
    return jam(name)


def jam(name):
    c.execute("select * from students where name = '" + name + "'")
    print(c.fetchall())
    conn.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```